# What is the best way to verify a deployment.yaml kubernetes file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-deployment

I have the following deployment.yaml file in Kuberentes:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: basic-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: basic
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: basic
        image: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: basic-config
```

I am not sure how I can fix the following error when I run `kubectl create -f basic-deployment.yaml`:

**The Deployment "basic-deployment" is invalid: spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string{"app":"basic"}: `selector` does not match template `labels`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: basic-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: basic
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: basic
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: basic
        image: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: basic-config
```

Basically, the selector match label in your deployment spec needs to match a label in your template. In your case, you have `app: nginx` as a matching label for the selector and you have `app: basic` in your template, so no match.

You would have to have something either one `app: nginx` or `app: basic` on both so that there is a match.